# svn commandline options to check in all files and not open the gui

Tags: tortoisesvn, command-line-arguments

Tortoise svn commandline tool is there a switch or an argument to check All files and to suppress the gui. I am working on source control automation.

```
TortoiseProc.exe /command:commit /path:"C:\SVN" /url:"http://mysvnserver/trunk" /closeonend:2
```

Comment: Stop using TortoiseProc and just use svn. `svn ci` will work for you. Use `svn help ci` from a command prompt to see the options.

Answer (score 1):

As Ken White alluded to in his comment, TortoiseSVN is not designed to be automated in a completely "silent" fashion. If that's your requirement, you should use `svn.exe` (which is installed with TortoiseSVN as an optional component, or you can get it standalone).

If there's a module/library for the environment you're working in (like SVNKit for Java, SharpSVN for .NET, PySVN for Python and SVN::Client for Perl), try to use that.

If you're using the command-line client, you'll use `svn commit c:\svn` but I'd suggest including a commit message too. See [`svn help commit`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.commit.html) for full details (`ci` is an alias for `commit`).

Comment: I installed silksvn. I have all the files to check-in from "myproj" folder on my local drive "C:\Temp\myproj" and commit all the files to the URL: http://svnserver.com/repos/trunk/misc/myproj
I tried using svn import and commit and ran into error "Commit target must be local path"                                                                                                         commands:
svn import -m "Test import" "C:\Temp\myproj" \ "http://svnserver.com/repos/trunk/misc/myproj" svn commit -m "Test import" "C:\Temp\myproj" \ "http://svnserver.com/repos/trunk/misc/myproj"

Comment: Why are you passing a URL to `svn commit`? The error message is pretty clear - you can only give a filesystem path to the client to commit. The URL it commits to is embedded in the working copy metadata. If you have basic usage questions about Subversion, please read the manual and open a new question.